# How can I draw a line around the colored pixels of an image at a specific offset?

Tags: javascript, opencv, image-processing

I'm using opencv for Javascript to generate the source image, which I place in a canvas' context via putImageData.

I need to draw a line around the red part of the image that is about 20 pixels away from the red. The second image is what I'm after... hand drawn, but hopefully you get the idea.

Simply cloning (into an overlaid canvas) and scaling an image behind the red image doesn't work (scaling isn't the right approach). I thought about using dilate but it doesn't seem to be reliable, and it's very slow.

[image: Red image needs offset]
[image: Goal]

---

**Update**: Per a commenter's request, here is an example of why dilation doesn't work well.

```
// Dilate the image
let src = cv.imread('canvasOffset');
let dst = new cv.Mat();
let M = cv.Mat.ones(40, 40, cv.CV_8U);
let anchor = new cv.Point(-1, -1);
cv.dilate(src, dst, M, anchor, 1, cv.BORDER_CONSTANT, 
cv.morphologyDefaultBorderValue());
cv.imshow('canvasOffset', dst);
src.delete(); dst.delete(); M.delete()
```

[image: Dilation]

Comment: `dilate` was my first thought. Can you show us how you're using it and provide an example when it doesn't achieve the results you want?

Comment: @beaker I have updated my post per your request.

Comment: “Doesn’t seem to be reliable” what does that mean? Dilation is the right approach here. Would be quite a bit faster than the solution by Jeru. But you should use a circular structuring element to get the effect you are looking for (leads to the same offset in all directions).

Comment: Whoa! Thank you, @CrisLuengo! I just switched the dilate structuring element to MORPH_ELLIPSE and it instantly did exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Cris Luengo this is solved.

I was able to use OpenCV's dilate with an elliptical structuring element. It does exactly what I needed.

Given a "canvasOffset" canvas containing the original image:

```
let src = cv.imread('canvasOffset');
let dst = new cv.Mat();
let M = new cv.Mat();
let ksize = new cv.Size(25, 25);
M = cv.getStructuringElement(cv.MORPH_ELLIPSE, ksize);
let anchor = new cv.Point(-1, -1);
cv.dilate(src, dst, M, anchor, 1, cv.BORDER_CONSTANT, cv.morphologyDefaultBorderValue());
cv.imshow('canvasOffset', dst);
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: this is truly a faster solution

Answer (score 0):

I have a simple solution implemented in Python.

1. First I converted the given image to a binary image where the red object is the region of interest (white)

[image]

2. Next I found contours using the built-in function available in OpenCV. I drew the resulting contour with **thick borders** on another image with black pixels having the same shape as the original image.

[image]

3. I found contours on this black image and drew the resulting contours on the original image. I drew contours with no thickness this time.

[image]

(As I said, the code is written in python, if you want me to share it)

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import os

path = r'C:\Users\Desktop\Stack\contour'
im = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path, 'handle.jpg'))
im = cv2.resize(im, (0, 0), fx=0.5, fy=0.5)         #--- resizing the image
im2 = im.copy()    #--- having another copy of the original image                       

imgray = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret2, th2 = cv2.threshold(imgray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
cv2.imshow('th2.jpg', th2)     #--- Image 1

_, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(th2, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnt = contours[0]

mask = np.zeros_like(im)
cv2.drawContours(mask, contours, -1, (255, 255, 255), 33)
cv2.imshow('mask.jpg', mask)    #--- Image 2

ret2, mask_th2 = cv2.threshold(mask[:,:,1], 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
_, contours1, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(mask_th2, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cv2.drawContours(im2, contours1, -1, (0, 0, 0), 2)
cv2.imshow('final.jpg', im2)    #--- Image 3

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: This is great! The python code would certainly help me. Most of my opencv work has been in Python; I'm trying the javascript library as a proof of concept.

Comment: @agileadam Hi there. Thanks for the interest. I have added the code.

Comment: Thank you, Jeru. I will try to re-create in JS.